# ArrayList confusion, words to numbers

Tags: java, arraylist

I have an ArrayList of `[1, 7, 2, 21, 18, 25, 3, 18, 25, 4, 1, 4]`

And an ArrayList of words: `[ag, bury, cry, dad]`

The number ArrayList contains each of the characters of the words, converted to their assigned int value.

Each number represents a letter of the alphabet; a = 1, b = 2, etc., etc.
Therefore, "ag" would be represented as "17"

How do I add the elements of the number list to a new ArrayList that would contain the number equivalent of the words: `[17, 2211825, 31825, 414]`? Is there an easier way to do this? Every combination of loops I have tried has failed me thus far. Any help?

P.S. No I am not asking you to do the entire project for me. This is just a small part of a project that involves sorting based on prime, composite, even, and odd numbers. This is the only part I'm tripped up on

Comment: Please show the code you have thus far.

Comment: Also, forget the list of words. How do you convert just *one word*?

Comment: If the characters are all ascii, you can take each number and add a fixed value to convert it to a character. (If lowercase, add 96 to each value. If uppercase add 64 to each value.) See: http://www.asciitable.com/. You can do the inverse (subtraction) to convert characters back into 1-indexed numbers.

Comment: Take word, check size, take as many elements from the other array and concatenate, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

```
import java.util.*;

public class HelloWorld{

    public static int getValue(char c) {
        return c-'a'+ 1;
    }

     public static void main(String []args){
        String data[] = {"ag", "bury", "cry", "dad"};
        List<String> input = Arrays.asList(data);
        List<String> result = new ArrayList<String>();
        for(int i=0;i<input.size();i++) {
            StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
            String item = input.get(i).toLowerCase();
            for(int j=0;j<item.length();j++){
                sb.append(getValue(item.charAt(j)));
            }
            result.add(sb.toString());
        }
        for(int i=0;i<result.size();i++)
            System.out.println(result.get(i));

     }


}
```

Hope This helps.
This is assuming mapping "a->1,b->2" and so on.
If not then some modifications need to be done

Comment: Writing code for other people to copy-paste when they didn't show any effort in solving their own problem doesn't help anyone.